# Pass sql date from talend to Rest Api

Tags: sql, spring-boot, rest, talend, sqldatetime

I want to send a post request to the rest API which includes an SQL date format, when I try to send the request with `YYYY-MM-DD` format, its showing bad request. How to properly send the data.

Comment: please share your code which will be much helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this below,

```
 @PostMapping("/date")
    public void date(@RequestParam("date") Date date) {
        // ...
    }
```

Explanation: It will pass date from post request.
you can also look at this [documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters)

I hope, it helps!